# Where can I specify in TokenValidationParameters that the algorithm in JWT token should match HS256?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I am using AspNet Core to build a web api and JWT tokens to authenticate users.

Where can I specify in `TokenValidationParameters` that the `alg` in token should match **HS256** (and never `none`)?

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            string jwtIssuer = configuration["JwtIssuer"];
            SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtKey"]));
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = jwtIssuer,
                ValidAudience = jwtIssuer,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
```

And does the library, by default, reject incoming tokens with `alg` set to `none`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1227#issuecomment-303822894) by default middleware doesn't allow `"alg": "none"`. Seems that is due to the exploit mentioned in the [question](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1227#issuecomment-368402053).

Regarding rejecting: I've tried to pass the token with with `"alg": "none"` and got `invalid_token` in the response (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.0`).

By the way, specification [requires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-8) implementation of `HS256` and `"none"` algorithms.